# The mathematics GRE score Advice- Should I send?

Tags: phd, gre, statistics

My GRE Score is 740(68%) and is only recommended when applying for a Ph.D in statistics. Is sending this score disadvantageous to me?

I did not take mathematical classes that are strongly required for admission. So, I studied those math subjects by myself and took GRE exam. By sending my score, could I prove I have some mathematical knowledge to admission committees?

Comment: If the schools you will be applying to require Math GRE, you won't have choice.